Distribution upgrade has stopped working. Should I force quit?
This morning I tried doing a distribution upgrade (after an update and on a fresh restart) from Ubuntu 24.04 to 24.10 and the process has completely stopped while installing snap gnome-46-2024.
I get a notification saying, "Oracular is not responding" I've clicked the 'Wait' button many times but it keeps popping back up. I did this for about 2 hours now.
Is it okay to force quit? I'm afraid it might mess something up...

So, I've been clicking the 'wait' button for close to 3 hours and it finally proceeded to finish the upgrade.

Kudos for being patient!
